# WordPress: difference between get_the_content() and the_content()

Tags: php, wordpress

I was working on the new theme in the WordPress and spent tons of time with the get_the_content() function.

```
  <div class="clearfix">
      <div>
        <p><?=get_the_content();?></p>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Seems that it doesn't process shortcuts and doesn't do paragraphs.

Then I replaced it with the the_content(); and my paragraphs and shortcuts started to work.

```
  <div class="clearfix">
      <div>
        <p><?=the_content();?></p>
      </div>
  </div>
```

My question: What is the difference between the functions and what additional processing the_content(); does comparing to get_the_content();?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While @J Quest provided an adequate answer, I'd like to elaborate a little bit. Generally speaking, WordPress has two types of post variable functions: `get_` functions and `the_` functions.

`get_` functions, such as [`get_the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/) or [`get_the_ID()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/)will return the desired information, which must then be manipulated and printed to the page. Some examples:

```
$content = get_the_content();
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
$content = str_replace( 'foo', 'bar', $content );

echo 'Post #'. get_the_ID() . $content;
```

`the_` functions, such as [`the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) and [`the_ID()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_id/) actually `echo` the returned value, and if applicable will apply the "default filters" for the appropriate values. These functions don't need to be echoed.

```
echo get_the_ID();
```

is functionally the same as

```
the_ID();
```

If you look at the docs for `the_ID()` you'll see it literally just outputs the value of `get_the_ID()`. From the source:

```
function the_ID() {
    echo get_the_ID();
}
```

In that vein, if you try and set `the_` functions as a variable, you'll leave a trail of echoed variables throughout the page.

```
$id = the_ID();
echo 'Post ID: '.$id;
```

will output:

```
123Post ID: 123
```

To use `get_the_content()` and get shortcodes to run, you'll either need to run it through the [`do_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) function, or better yet `the_content` filter.

```
$content = get_the_content();

echo do_shortcode( $content );
// Or:    
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
```

If you just need to spit out post content in a template, without any manipulation, you're typically better off with (no echo or echo short tag):

```
the_content();
```

Answer (score 1):

`get_the_content()` does not pass the content through `the_content`. Which means that it does not auto-embed videos, or expand shortcodes, among other things.

Just use `get_the_content()` and it will remove those tags.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/