# Wordpress WP_Query result array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying make my wordpress homepage to show only 2 blogpost. with different showing element. one of them is float-left and one is float-right. on native php it's easy to fetch result as array. and print them with `$result[0]` and `$result[1]`.

But on wordpress idk to do that.
maybe u guys can help me to guide any documentation.
like wp_query or etc. and dont forget to give me an example line of code

*sorry my english was so bad. I hope you guys read this and reply to this.

My current line of code is:

```
$blogposts = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
    ));
while ($blogposts->have_posts()) {
        $blogposts->the_post();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're more comfortable with arrays, you can always make use of the [`get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) function instead, which takes arguments (almost) exactly like the [`WP_Query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) Class. `get_posts()` actually makes use of `WP_Query` as well.

That said, your code wouldn't be all that difficult to modify with "native PHP" as you mentioned. It's just a [`while`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) loop instead of a [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop, both of which are similar control structures.

All you have to do is add a counter variable and increment it after each pass using the [increment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) operator: `++`;

Here's a quick code sample for you:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $query->have_posts() ){
    $count = 0; // Start a Counter

    while( $query->have_posts() ){
        $query->the_post();

        printf( '<div class="post float-%s">', ($count++ % 2 == 0) ? 'left' : 'right' ); // If counter is odd: "left", even: "right"
            printf( '<h4 class="post-title">%s</h4>', get_the_title() );
            the_content();
        echo '</div>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'No Posts Found.';
}
```

A couple of things:

- I moved the `$args` array to its own variable. Some queries can get pretty complex, having them as a designated variable can improve long-term maintainability.
- You also don't need the `post_type` argument if you just want `post`, because that's the default value.
- I added an `if` clause, so if your posts ever disappeared or you moved this code, there'd be a fall back for "nothing found".
- I used a bit of a complex [Ternary Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) in the post class. I increment it there so we don't need another line to increment the `$count` later, and it removes the need for a multi-line "if/else" to determine `left` or `right`.
- Beyond that, you didn't provide a markup structure so I made use of a [`the_` and `get_the_` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50892776/wordpress-difference-between-get-the-content-and-the-content) if you're unaware of the difference.

Comment: omg, i never thinking about that. This is a very good idea. when I add $count to my if statement. thanks, problem solved.. :)